# Difference between using XHR and script src

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome, xmlhttprequest

I saw this issue in Chrome, but will love to hear your answers about other browsers as well.

A script to domain `thirdparty.com` has been called from a website X (I call the script from js, not through the HTML).

```
<script src="http://www.thirdparty.com/example"></script>
```

I see that time after time this script is being queued before downloaded.

When I changed the call to the script to an *XHR* call (with `eval`), the script was downloaded without being queued first.

Can you please explain this issue to me? is it only a coincidence?

Comment: Can you please provice screenshots of the `queue` in the 2 scenarios? paste links and I will edit your post and replace the links with the images

Comment: I don't think you can access the xhr results and `eval` the text if it's a thirdparty domain script.

Comment: @Bergi, I am the third-party owner, and I can ask the developer of website X to add me to his webpage by script src or by adding an XHR + eval.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to some clever colleague, I have found these resources that describes the different resource priorities of a browser:

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/resource-prioritization

https://css-tricks.com/the-critical-request/

https://medium.com/reloading/preload-prefetch-and-priorities-in-chrome-776165961bbf

Based on these links - XHR is having a higher resource priority than script src.